# Store Group Membership in an Array using VBscript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I am trying to store AD group members including nested in an array. I have a group which has two groups as it's members, but when i run the script, the array contains the group membership of only the last group. Please help me correct the below script.

```
Dim arrmembers(1000)
Dim i

strTargetGroupDN_Remove = "LDAP://CN=GroupNameL,OU=Client,DC=testDC=com" 
EnumNestedgroup strTargetGroupDN_Remove

Function EnumNestedgroup(strGroupDN_Remove)

    Set objGroup_Remove = GetObject(strGroupDN_Remove)
    i=0

    For Each objMember_Remove in objGroup_Remove.Members
        If (LCase(objMember_Remove.Class) = "group") Then 
            EnumNestedgroup objMember_Remove.AdsPath  
        Else 
            arrmembers(i) = objMember_Remove.SAMaccountname
            i=i+1
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not reset your counter to 0 (`i = 0`) **in** your recursive function (which isn't a function btw).